# Kerberos authentication on iPhone

Tags: iphone, kerberos

Are there any libraries for kerberos authentication for iPhone? Heimdal doesn't have a build for iOS.

Are there any examples for using Kerberos to Authenticate to Active Directory server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Apple does not provide a GSS-API for/on iOS, you are out of luck. You should consult the iOS dev forums at Apple's website. A simple Google search shows that there is no support.

Answer (score 2):

iOS 5 (maybe even earlier) does have a GSS.framework that supports Kerberos.

I'm not entirely sure how to use it, though. Apple has sample code here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/KerberosGSS/

Comment: It should be fairly easy to adapt for iOS, though.

Answer (score 1):

Well, Apple says there is somewhat support for GSS API in iOS.
But Apple documentation is rather poor on this topic, surprisingly. There is remark in the [What's New in iOS 5: General System Security Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS5.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30915195-SW1), referencing RFC 2743 (which is all about GSS API including Kerberos) and header files for more details. One line can be seen in [iOS Technology Overview: Device Frameworks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/iPhoneOSFrameworks/iPhoneOSFrameworks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898-CH6-SW3)

When you look at `/System/Library/Frameworks/GSS.framework/Versions/A/Headers` you can find these headers there:

- `gssapi_krb5.h`
- `gssapi_netlogon.h`
- `gssapi_ntlm.h`
- `gssapi_spnego.h`
- `gssapi.h`

#### Excerpt from gssapi_krb5.h:

```
...
/*
 * kerberos mechanism specific functions
 */

struct krb5_ccache_data;

OM_uint32 GSSAPI_LIB_FUNCTION gss_krb5_copy_ccache
(OM_uint32 * /*minor*/,
 gss_cred_id_t /*cred*/,
 struct krb5_ccache_data * /*out*/);

OM_uint32 GSSAPI_LIB_FUNCTION
gss_krb5_ccache_name(OM_uint32 * /*minor_status*/,
             const char * /*name */,
             const char ** /*out_name */);

OM_uint32 GSSAPI_LIB_FUNCTION gsskrb5_register_acceptor_identity
        (const char * /*identity*/);

OM_uint32 GSSAPI_LIB_FUNCTION krb5_gss_register_acceptor_identity
    (const char * /*identity*/);

OM_uint32 GSSAPI_LIB_FUNCTION
gsskrb5_extract_authz_data_from_sec_context
    (OM_uint32 * /*minor_status*/,
     gss_ctx_id_t /*context_handle*/,
     int /*ad_type*/,
     gss_buffer_t /*ad_data*/);

/*
 * Function declarations
 */

OM_uint32 GSSAPI_LIB_FUNCTION
gss_krb5_export_lucid_sec_context(OM_uint32 *minor_status,
                  gss_ctx_id_t *context_handle,
                  OM_uint32 version,
                  void **kctx);


OM_uint32 GSSAPI_LIB_FUNCTION
gss_krb5_free_lucid_sec_context(OM_uint32 *minor_status,
                void *kctx);

OM_uint32 GSSAPI_LIB_FUNCTION
gss_krb5_set_allowable_enctypes(OM_uint32 *minor_status,
                gss_cred_id_t cred,
                OM_uint32 num_enctypes,
                int32_t *enctypes);

GSSAPI_CPP_END
...
```

So one would expect that there must be some support. As I'm SO rookie and have low reputation at the moment, I can provide only two links.