# Supporting Kerberos requests from iOS devices

Tags: android, ios, authentication, impersonation, kerberos

I have a web application that is designed for mobile devices to view reporting information. The application is written in ASP .Net MVC 3 and communicates to various reporting services servers, Analysis servers and SQL Servers around the corporate network. Each of these communications is supported through the Windows / Negotiate authentication protocol and by using Kerberos with various SPN settings configured.

The site is also available externally so that anyone outwith the network environment could log into the site using their windows credentials. This works for laptops and BlackBerry's which are setup to support kerberos on the BES server.

Is there anyway to set up iPhone / iPad / Android devices to authenticate using kerberos? At the moment these devices simply refuse to login using kerberos. If I revert the site to using NTLM or Basic authentication then the devices can authenticate but the web server can no longer connect to the various data sources on behalf of the current users' permissions.

Is this a common scenario that others are facing with mobile reporting and if so are there any general solutions to the issue?

Thanks,
Brian.

Comment: There is no built-in support for Kerberos in iOS. Read my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867680/kerberos-authentication-on-iphone).